# Pythonを使ってWordPressへ複数のタグがついた記事を投稿したい

Tags: python, wordpress

PythonでWordPressに記事を投稿していますが、
記事に指定した複数のタグを認識させることができません。

Aのタグ、Bのタグ、Cのタグ……というようにそれぞれ独立したタグをつけたいのですが、
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, Hという名前の一つのタグとして認識されてしまいます。

ひとつひとつ別のタグとして反映させるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```py
tag = “A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H”

post.terms_names = {
  'post_tag': [tag],
  'category': [category]
}
```

下記のように直接タグの名前を打ち込む場合は別々のタグと認識されているようです。

```py
post.terms_names = {
    "post_tag": ["Python", "WordPress"],
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `'post_tag': tag.split(', '),` としてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/324331 にて解決済のようです。